# issue finding route in node js rest api with express and ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, es6-class

I'm trying to setup a REST api with Node.js but I want to do it using ES6 classes, my app.js looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

class ApplicationServer {

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.initExpress();
        this.initExpressMiddleWare();
        this.initControllers();
        this.start();
    }

    initExpress() {
        this.app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    }

    initExpressMiddleWare() {
        this.app.use(morgan("dev"));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    }

    initControllers() {
        require('./controllers/CountryController')(this.app);
    }

    start() {
        this.app.listen(this.app.get('port'), () =>{
            console.log(`Server listening for port: ${this.app.get('port')}`);
        });
    }
}

new ApplicationServer();
```

Everything works fine, the server start and listen over port 3000, no problem at all, but if you see I'm trying to initialize all my controllers from the `initControllers()` method using require. The `CountryController.js` file contains a class with the following code:

```
class CountryController {

    contructor(app) {
        this.app = app;
        this.getCountries();
    }

    getCountries() {
        this.app.get('api/country', (req, res) => {
            res.json([]);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = ( app ) => { return new CountryController( app ) }
```

After this I didn't get any error when I run the server but when I tried to call the api method `localhost:3000/api/country` I always get:

> GET /api/country 404 4.375 ms - 150

It seems like it is not recognizing the route.
Any help to find what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revoke my answer. I no longer want to support this site.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work neither, it seems to be other the problem. Thanks

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera So you need to use /api/country with the preceding forward slash and I just noticed you also misspelled `constructor` in your CountryController. Changing both of those things gets it working for me.

Comment: Thanks so much, you are right that was the issue `misspelled ` I was sleepy i guess. Thanks